# Using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and if/else statement?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, if-else

I have been working on this code for awhile and I can't make it work the way I need it to.  The code is suppose to move a feature according to a set distance from types in a designated field. As the code is now the point features move at the angle and distance for 
    elif Type == 'Type2':
        distance = .707107

in the code below. The problem might be the updateCursor or in_features causing the if statement to be ignored. I am still new to python and arcpy but I would like to get this code to work.

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from math import radians, sin, cos

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def move():
    def shift_features(in_features, x_shift, y_shift):
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + x_shift, row[0][1] + y_shift]])
    return

    infc = "Point.shp"
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(infc)
    for row in rows:
        x = row.Easting
        y = row.Northing
        Type = row.feat_Type
        if Type == 'Type1':
            distance = .3535535 

        elif Type == 'Type2':
            distance = .707107

        else:
            print Type

    shift_features(infc, distance * sin(radians(45)), distance * cos(radians(45)))

#Variables for creating the XY event
infc = r'Database Connections\Test.odc\Units'
x_coords = "Easting"
y_coords = "Northing"
z_coords = ""

out_Layer = "points_layer"
Saved_Layer = "Point.shp"

# Add a spatial reference to the new shapefile
prjfile = "C:/data/LocalGrid.prj"
spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjfile)

# Make the XY event layer...
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(infc, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer, spRef, z_coords)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_Layer, Saved_Layer)
move()


# Print feature count and messages
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Also I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1

---

Here is the new code, it looks like it is actually skipping the shift_features function.  Also, I have tried taking it out of the def move(): function but I get the same results.

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from math import radians, sin, cos

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def move():
    def shift_features(in_features):
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ('SHAPE@XY', 'feat_type')) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[1] == 'Type1':
                    distance = .3535535 
                elif row[1] == 'Type2':
                    distance = .707107 
                else:
                    print row[1]
                    distance = 0 
                cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + distance * sin(radians(45)), row[0][1] + distance * cos(radians(45))]])
    return 0
    infc = "Point.shp"
    shift_features(infc)

#Variables for creating the XY event
infc = r'Database Connections\Test.odc\Units'
x_coords = "Easting"
y_coords = "Northing"
z_coords = ""

out_Layer = "points_layer"
Saved_Layer = "Point.shp"

# Add a spatial reference to the new shapefile
prjfile = "C:/data/LocalGrid.prj"
spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjfile)

# Make the XY event layer...
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(infc, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer, spRef, z_coords)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_Layer, Saved_Layer)
move()


# Print feature count and messages
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your shift_feature is applied **after** the loop of your search cursor, so only the last value is used and applied for all your features.

What I recommend is to avoid using 2 cursors when you can do it with one cursor.

```
    def shift_features(in_features):
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ('SHAPE@XY', 'feat_type')) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[1] == 'Type1':
                    distance = .3535535 
                elif row[1] == 'Type2':
                    distance = .707107 
                else:
                    print row[1]
                    distance = 0 
                cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + distance * sin(radians(45)), row[0][1] + distance * cos(radians(45))]], row[1])
            del cursor
       return 0
```

Comment: I changed the code  but the points are not shifting, and the else: statement does not print. I kept the original code the same but just changed the UpdateCursor (def shift_features) to one cursor.

Comment: please edit your question with your new code.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to focus on the part of your code with the shift_features function, since I can reproduce what you are trying to do there. Firstly, I don't think you need to have a def within a def, and so you could keep it simpler by removing one of them. And, though you provide for a feature class to be passed to shift_features, you then set it within the move() module, which does not allow you to pass a different feature class because it is hard-coded in your module.

Here is some code that I was able to get to shift my points by the amount specified. This code worked in the python window in ArcMap on an arbitrary shapefile (that I called "Points.shp".)

```
def shift_features(in_features):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ('SHAPE@XY', 'feat_type')) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1] == 'Type1':
                distance = .3535535
            elif row[1] == 'Type2':
                distance = .707107
            else:
                print row[1]
                distance = 0
            xshift = row[0][0] + distance * math.sin(math.radians(45))
            yshift = row[0][1] + distance * math.cos(math.radians(45))
            row[0] = [xshift, yshift]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I separated out some things so I could debug better. I can't verify whether the rest of your code works, but here is how I would insert this into your other code:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, math

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def shift_features(in_features):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ('SHAPE@XY', 'feat_type')) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1] == 'Type1':
                distance = .3535535
            elif row[1] == 'Type2':
                distance = .707107
            else:
                print row[1]
                distance = 0
            xshift = row[0][0] + distance * math.sin(math.radians(45))
            yshift = row[0][1] + distance * math.cos(math.radians(45))
            row[0] = [xshift, yshift]
            cursor.updateRow(row)

#Variables for creating the XY event
infc = r'Database Connections\Test.odc\Units'
x_coords = "Easting"
y_coords = "Northing"
z_coords = ""

out_Layer = "points_layer"
Saved_Layer = "Point.shp"

# Add a spatial reference to the new shapefile
prjfile = "C:/data/LocalGrid.prj"
spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjfile)

# Make the XY event layer...
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(infc, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer, spRef, z_coords)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_Layer, Saved_Layer)
shift_features(Saved_Layer)


# Print feature count and messages
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: Also, I imported the math lib and then used math.sin, math.cos, and math.radians, but the way you do it works too (from math import sin, radians). I meant to change that back.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am concerned wrapping the function in another function is not necessary, so 'def move():' and can be removed. Then you should pass an existing object to your function "shift_features", which accepts one parameter ("in_features"). For example:

```
shift_features(Saved_Layer)
```

Comment: I did that and now I get:  TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row for    cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0]     + distance * sin(radians(45)), row[0][1] + distance * cos(radians(45))]])

Comment: I recommend you first calclate the x and y shift and then pass the values into the updateCursor. So something like:  cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + (x_shift or 0), row[0][1] + (y_shift or 0)]])

Comment: Please let us know what the problem was and how you solved it.